# How can i set tow <ul> in wp_nav_menu in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a problem to set two ul in wp_nav_menu.
i have set like following code in html. i want to set in wp_nav_menu.
my code is.

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse menu-header-menu-container" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"> 
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="index.html" title="Home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="about-us.html" title="About Us">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="athletes.html" title="Athletes">Athletes</a></li>
            <li><a href="coach.html" title="Coach">Coach</a></li>
            <li><a href="colleges.html" title="Colleges">Colleges</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact-us.html" title="Contact Us">Contact Us</a></li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="user-action hidden-xs">
            <li><a href="Javascript:void(0);" title="Search">Seach</a></li>
            <li><a href="Javascript:void(0);" title="Key">Login</a></li>
            <li><a href="Javascript:void(0);" title="User">Register</a></li>
          </ul>
 </div>
```

So anyone can help me how to set two ul in wp_nav_menu.

Answer (score 1):

First thing you need to do is register the 2 menus in the functions.php file.

```
function register_menus() {
  register_nav_menus(
    array(
      'menu-1' => __('Primary Menu'),
      'menu-2' => __('Secondary Menu')
    )
  );
}
add_action('init', 'register_menus');
```

Then in the WordPress dashboard under **Appearance > Menus** create the menus.

Be sure to set the theme locations to *'Primary Menu'* and *'Secondary Menu'*.

Place the following code where you want the menus to display (most likely header.php).

```
<?php wp_nav_menu(array('menu' => 'menu-1', 'container' => '<ul>', 'menu_class' => 'nav navbar-nav')); ?>
<?php wp_nav_menu(array('menu' => 'menu-2', 'container' => '<ul>', 'menu_class' => 'user-action hidden-xs')); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If someone else has issues to fetch the right menu, you can try to exchange 'menu' to 'theme_location'.

```
<?php wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location' => 'menu-1', 'container' => '<ul>', 'menu_class' => 'marquee__inner')); ?>
```